# PYCURL get a json file with utf-8 encoding problems

Tags: python, utf-8, pycurl

i'm facing a problem with my PYCURL request.
My json file on the server is encoded in utf-8 and look like this :

```
{
  "address" : "123 rue de Labège"
}
```

I use PYCURL to get this json and copy it into a new file on my computer.
I use Python 2.7 and here is my setup for PYCURL :

```
def setup(self, _url, _method, _login, _passwd, _path, *args, **kwargs):
    self.curl = pycurl.Curl()
    self.url = 'https://%s:%d/' % (self.ip, self.port) + _url
    self.method = _method
    self.userpwd = '%s:%s' % (_login, _passwd)
    self.path = _path

    self.curl.setopt(pycurl.URL, self.url)

    curl_method = {
        "GET": pycurl.HTTPGET,
        "POST": pycurl.POST
    }

    if self.method in curl_method:
        self.curl.setopt(curl_method[self.method], 1)
    else:
        self.curl.setopt(pycurl.CUSTOMREQUEST, self.method)

    self.curl.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0)
    self.curl.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0)
    self.curl.setopt(pycurl.HTTPAUTH, pycurl.HTTPAUTH_BASIC)
    self.curl.setopt(pycurl.USERPWD, self.userpwd)

    if _url == 'MY_FILE_JSON':
        filename = 'file.json'
        self.file = open(self.path + filename, 'wb')
        self.curl.setopt(pycurl.WRITEDATA, self.file)
```

The problem is in the file i'm getting :

```
{
  "address" : "123 rue de Lab\u00e8uge"
}
```

I don't understand why PYCURL encoding my "è" into \u00e8.
Is there any option with setopt with PYCURL to force it to print the good character ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually this is totally correct, once you do a `print` of the variable property, you can see it prints out fine.

This is just how Python internally handles Unicode strings. Once PycURL receives the file it will be converted to whatever type is appropriate for the property. In your case this is a Unicode string.

Check [this article](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) out for more information.

So to recap, if you do:

```
>>> test = u'123 rue de Lab\u00e8uge'
>>> print(test)
123 rue de Labèuge
```

Here you can see I create a Unicode string (starting with the `u`).

Comment: alright I know how to print it good in my script but I don't know how to get the document with the gode encodage with the pycurl request directly.

Comment: See that's the thing; the document is already in the right encoding. What are you trying to do, where you see it going wrong?

Comment: Ok I understand ! That's how special characters are encoded in json files but for user, it's transparent. Thank you

Comment: No problem, have fun!